# Python Pandas Outer Join for Duplicate records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

if there is a duplicate record in second dataframe (like 'Houston' in below case) and i want to print only one Houston in the final output after doing outer join (as only one Houston is present in first data frame) but its not happening and in the final output after outer join, Houston is repeating in left dataframe also as mentioned below. Pl see the below test data. Pl help.

DataFrame -1

```
ID1 City Population 
1 CHICAGO 3000 
5 HOUSTON 14000 
7 NEW JERSEY 18000 
7 NEW JERSEY 20000
```

DataFrame -2

```
ID2 City POPULATION 
4 ARIZONA 2000 
5 HOUSTON 3000 
5 HOUSTON 4000 
5 HOUSTON 5000 
7 NEW JERSEY 3000 
8 MICHIGAN 4000
```

```py
det = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    left_on=['ID1'],
    right_on=['ID2'],
    how='outer',
    indicator='indicator',
    suffixes=('_A','_B'),
)
```

Expected Output:

```
ID1 City_A Population ID2 City_B POPULATION indicator
0 1.0 CHICAGO 3000.0 NaN NaN NaN left_only
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 3000.0 both
2 5.0 NaN NaN NaN HOUSTON 4000.0 both
3 5.0 NaN 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 5000.0 both
4 7.0 NEW JERSEY 18000.0 7.0 NEW JERSEY 3000.0 both
5 7.0 NEW JERSEY 20000.0 7.0 NaN 0 both
6 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 ARIZONA 2000.0 right_only
7 NaN NaN NaN 8.0 MICHIGAN 4000.0 right_only
```

## Actual Output:

ID1 City_A Population ID2 City_B POPULATION indicator
0 1.0 CHICAGO 3000.0 NaN NaN NaN left_only
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 3000.0 both
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 4000.0 both
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 5000.0 both
4 7.0 NEW JERSEY 18000.0 7.0 NEW JERSEY 3000.0 both
5 7.0 NEW JERSEY 20000.0 7.0 NEW JERSEY 3000.0 both
6 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 ARIZONA 2000.0 right_only
7 NaN NaN NaN 8.0 MICHIGAN 4000.0 right_only

For Ex: I am expecting Houston for other 2 values should display as NaN as its not present in Left Data Frame. But Outer join prints the 'Houston' in left data frame . so it looks like there are 3 Houston present in both right and left Dataframe.

## Expected Output:

ID1 City_A Population ID2 City_B POPULATION indicator
0 1.0 CHICAGO 3000.0 NaN NaN NaN left_only
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 3000.0 both
2 5.0 NaN NaN NaN HOUSTON 4000.0 both
3 5.0 NaN NaN NaN HOUSTON 5000.0 both
4 7.0 NEW JERSEY 18000.0 7.0 NEW JERSEY 3000.0 both
5 NaN NaN NaN 7.0 NaN 0 both
6 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 ARIZONA 2000.0 right_only
7 NaN NaN NaN 8.0 MICHIGAN 4000.0 right_only

Comment: Outer join is returning the results as it is expected. You can further apply your filter criteria to filter out records as per your need.

Comment: Outer join is returning 'Houston' 3 times in left dataframe that actually i don't want . Is there any inbuilt function in pandas to handle this ? :          ID1 City_A Population ID2 City_B POPULATION indicator
0 1.0 CHICAGO 3000.0 NaN NaN NaN left_only
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 3000.0 both
2 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 4000.0 both
3 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 5000.0 both
4 7.0 NEW JERSEY 18000.0 7.0 NEW JERSEY 3000.0 both
5 7.0 NEW JERSEY 20000.0 7.0 NEW JERSEY 3000.0 both
6 NaN NaN NaN 4.0 ARIZONA 2000.0 right_only
7 NaN NaN NaN 8.0 MICHIGAN 4000.0 right_only

Comment: Please clearly specify your requirement your input and the expected output :)

Comment: I just want the outer join should print the one to one match and if there is a key mismatch like in this case Houston is not present in left DF but its present in right DF so in result it should print as one:                                                                                
1 5.0 HOUSTON 14000.0 5.0 HOUSTON 3000.0 both
2 5.0 NaN NaN NaN HOUSTON 4000.0 both
3 5.0 NaN NaN NaN HOUSTON 5000.0 both